# Why is my chart displaying differently than I expect from my if statements?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to display some kind of log information for myself on the chart, but I experience some unreliable behaviour of Pinescript in this case. In the code I have the same if cases for plotting the information, but on the chart they were displayed differently.

Has anyone experienced the same unreliability or does someone see my mistake?

[image: Pinescript]

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Also, do you realize that you have several warnings which could cause the issue? Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The problem was that I have that conditions to check with method `wasAreaAbovePrice` and `wasAreaBelowPrice` and then write a 2 or 3 in the chart. In case of the plotchar in line 62, 63 it worked, but not in line 68, 70. First occurence in the chart has in plotchar 2 and 3, but in label only 3 and on the second occurence it worked correctly.

The solution was to bring the calculation outside the if, so the calculation can work on every iteration. So read the warnings ;)
Thanks @vitruvius

Comment: without a working code example we can not help you.

Answer (score 1):

Calling functions in local scope is generally not a good idea. If you function has loops or uses the history referencing operator, you will break the history and have an inconsistent behavior.

Move your function call to the global scope and it should be good.